# Automate UI Tests in a Kotlin Compose Project - equivalent version of Expresso Recorder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, ui-automation, expresso

is there a framework I can use to automate UI regression testing in a Kotlin Compose project? Clicking on Android Studio `Run -> Record Expresso Test` gives a warning that `Espresso Testing Framework does not support Compose projects.`

Comment: Do anybody know google team plans about it?

Answer (score 1):

Espresso testing framework cannot be used with Jetpack Compose so test recording is not yet available but Compose tests are fairly easy to write.

You can check the official documentation if this helps: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing

dupe: [Test recorder for jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71287057/test-recorder-for-jetpack-compose)